# HTTP STATUS 404 /Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404

I am not able to run a link. After hitting the link, it shows:

> "http status 404" - requested resource is not available.

Although, I think from my side, I did my best as its just simple code of one dispatcher servlet and the respective output file - `HelloPage.jsp`
attaching screen shot of my directory structure and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

What's wrong with my setup?

[image: directory structure]

[image: dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Comment: share your whole code here probably the problem would be in url mapping

Comment: Please add your code (dispatcher-servlet.xml) directly in stead of posting screenshots of it. More information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: oops!! missed the response. I solved my problem. It was related to inappropriate lib files. thanks a lot for your attention guys. :)